# std::stack with std::vector as underlying container of user-defined type is not working, why?

Tags: c++, vector, stack

**According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) and from my best knowledge, I know that `std::vector`, `std::list`, and `std::dequeue` (default) can be used as the underlying container in a stack.**.

I have implemented a Quick Sort Algorithm using Iteration.
To simulate Recursion, I am using `std::stack`.

My program is behaving very strange. It seems that it is stuck in an infinite loop and I am unable to figure out why, and which part of my program is causing it, when I am using `std::vector` as my underlying container in the `std::stack`:

`std::stack<StackElement, std::vector<StackElement>> recStack;`

Here below is my `QuickSort` implementation class with `std::vector` as the underlying container:

```
class QuickSort
  {
  public: 
    void sort (int arr[], int start, int endIndex)
    {

      std::stack<StackElement, std::vector<StackElement>> recStack; 
      recStack.push(StackElement(start, endIndex, 0, -1));
      
      while (!recStack.empty())
      {
        auto top = recStack.top(); 

        // Anchor 
        if (top.start >= top.endIndex){
          recStack.pop(); 
          continue; 
        }

        // find Pivote if not calcualted 
        if (top.pivote == -1)  {
          top.pivote = partition(arr, top.start, top.endIndex); 
        }

        // Decision on the basis of which specific subArray has to be sorted 
        if (top.sortStep == SORT_LEFT){
            recStack.push(StackElement(start, top.pivote-1, 0, -1));
            top.sortStep = SORT_RIGHT; // next time sort right subarray 
        }
        else if (top.sortStep == SORT_RIGHT)
        {
          StackElement ele(top.pivote+1, top.endIndex, 0, -1);  // right subArray 
          recStack.pop(); 
          recStack.push(ele); 
        }
      }
    }
   private: 
    struct StackElement
    {
      int start; 
      int endIndex; 
      bool sortStep; 
      int pivote; 

      StackElement(int st, int end, bool step, int piv): 
        start(st), endIndex(end), sortStep(step), pivote(piv){  } 
      
      StackElement() = default; 
    };  
    
    enum STEP {SORT_LEFT = 0, SORT_RIGHT = 1}; 

    int partition(int arr[], int st, int end)
    {
      int pivot = rand(st, end); 
      int i = st; 

      for (int j=st; j<=end; ++j)
      {
        if (arr[j] < arr[pivot])
        {
          std::swap(arr[j], arr[i]);

          if(i == pivot) pivot = j; // new Pivot

          i += 1; 
        }
      }

      // Place Pivot element 
      std::swap(arr[i], arr[pivot]); 

      return i; // index of pivote element 
    }
  

    int rand(int min, int max)
    {
      /*code to generate random number in the range*/
    }
```

The interesting part is that, when I use `std::dequeue` (which is the default) and `std::list` as the underlying container, it is working smoothly and producing the correct result without being stuck in an infinite loop, unlike with `std::vector`.

I tried to use `std::vector` as the underlying container with some primitive data types like `int`, `float`, and it was working without any problem.

I even tried it with my `StackElement` type and it was working.

Here is the sample code:

```
stack<Iteration::QuickSort::StackElement, std::vector<Iteration::QuickSort::StackElement>> stack; 
  stack.push({3, 5, 0, 2}); 
  stack.push({3, 5, 0, 2}); 
  stack.push({3, 5, 0, 2}); 
  stack.push({3, 5, 1, 2}); 
  stack.push({3, 5, 0, 2}); 
  stack.pop(); 

  while(!stack.empty())
  {
    cout<< stack.top().pivote<< endl; 
    stack.pop(); 
  }
```

I don't know why it is not working in my sort function.

Please help me identify why it is happening, and what details I am missing, so that I will take care for next time.

Comment: Side note `void sort (int arr[], int start, int endIndex)` is not how we write C++ anymore.  If you can use std::span<int> in any case get rid of your unsized "C" style array

Comment: Please show a [mre]. The above doesn't compile - or are you asking _why_ it doesn't?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code line-by-line at runtime and look at your data to see why the algorithm is getting stuck in the infinite loop?

Comment: The code you posted above doesn't make sense.  You create a `auto top` variable at the start of a loop.  And then just before you finish the loop you modify it, then discard it immediately.  I suspect your real code has a reference, which would explain why `deque` and `vector` change what happens.  Post **actual code** that **actually reproduces** your **actual problem** - a [mcve].  Simplify the code, then CHECK that the simplified code actually reproduces the problem, then post the simplified code.  You appear to have simplified without doing the check.

Comment: `top.sortStep = SORT_RIGHT` You seem to expect that this updates an element sitting on the stack. It does not - it updates its copy in a local variable. Since `if (top.sortStep == SORT_RIGHT)` condition is never true, most elements pushed on the stack are never popped off it, the stack never becomes empty, and the loop runs forever.